# how to double count in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count

I am making instargram ERD. I use mysql to make it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LObv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOeOx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO8Nj.png)

here's my table user, post, and follow.

I want to make profile page, so i coded below.

```
select u.user, 
       u.name, 
       u.introduce, 
       u.profileImage,
       ifnull(count(p.postIdx),0) as postCount,
       ifnull(count(f.followingIdx),0) as followerCount
from user as u
left outer join post as p on u.userIdx = p.userIdx
left outer join follow as f on u.userIdx = f.followingIdx
group by u.userIdx;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJHGs.png)

but result was not i expected.

can you guys help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: don't  post (only)  data sample as image  .. post data sample and expected  result as tabular text  ..

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time using this site, and English is not my main language. So I didn't know how to upload it.

Comment: @kapr Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You only need to show the columns that are needed for the question.